# How to Change colors IF in geom_bar ggplot2, IFelse dont work

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

Why the operator if does not work in this context?

[image]

The main file with data

```
    structure(list(age = c("0-4", "05-09", "10-14", "15-19", "20-24", 
"25-29", "30-34", "35-39", "40-44", "45-49", "50-54", "55-59", 
"60-64", "65-69", "70-74", "75-79", "80-84", "85+", "0-4", "05-09", 
"10-14", "15-19", "20-24", "25-29", "30-34", "35-39", "40-44", 
"45-49", "50-54", "55-59", "60-64", "65-69", "70-74", "75-79", 
"80-84", "85+", "0-4", "05-09", "10-14", "15-19", "20-24", "25-29", 
"30-34", "35-39", "40-44", "45-49", "50-54", "55-59", "60-64", 
"65-69", "70-74", "75-79", "80-84", "85+", "0-4", "05-09", "10-14"
), gender = c("F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M"), year = c(2011, 2011, 
2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 
2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 
1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 2011, 2011, 2011
), pop = c(25.4759696688669, 21.129961995163, 20.711726947066, 
27.4762242467223, 30.8584728965505, 31.4039968723292, 38.3503354972451, 
39.695961304166, 31.476733402433, 31.6403905951667, 32.6405178840943, 
38.2048624370374, 38.7867546778681, 28.4945356681759, 21.4390922481043, 
17.5658720200753, 14.3109122979288, 9.47393304602404, 21.1892611493233, 
27.4018193920568, 30.7299755935212, 31.8208712373345, 39.4571407440278, 
39.8639153908735, 31.0627912136676, 31.2846682937653, 33.2815620146439, 
39.4756305007026, 40.751423711264, 30.7854448635456, 25.3494564011538, 
24.0921529472672, 25.330966644479, 21.6699948228681, 8.20945196361216, 
1.92293469417942, 29.7360023208587, 31.567304902814, 40.125471424427, 
40.9413983173774, 31.404119524224, 31.3134609805628, 31.9299390774587, 
38.6568030171163, 40.361183637946, 30.1892950391645, 25.1486800116043, 
26.2365825355382, 29.3552364374819, 30.4794023788802, 16.1372207716855, 
18.53060632434, 13.6713083841021, 6.67246881346098, 28.4036150055462, 
22.8210863200771, 22.020984488935)), row.names = c(NA, 57L), class = "data.frame")
```

It was the part of the file with basic data. It is not clear how to make different colors for the left and right sides of 2001. I want to make a comparison of two age structures, and the ideal would be to make different colors on either side of the graph for only one year

```
library(dplyr)
        library(tidyr)
        library (ggthemes)
        library(readxl)
        library(ggplot2)
        pyramidRak1 <- read_excel("~/MetodyVSG/U3/Rstudio/pyramidRak1.xlsx")
        df3= data.frame(pyramidRak1)
        rgb.val <- col2rgb("white")
        t.col <- rgb(rgb.val[1], rgb.val[2], rgb.val[3],
                     max = 255,
                     alpha = (100 - 99) * 255 / 100,
                     names = "blue")
        
        ggplot(data = df3, aes(x = age, y = pop, fill = (as.factor(year)), color=gender,width = 1)) +
          geom_bar(data = df3 %>% filter(gender == "F", year != 2011) %>% arrange(rev(year)),
                   stat = "identity",
                   position = "identity") +
          geom_bar(data = df3 %>% filter(gender == "M", year != 2011) %>% arrange(rev(year)),
                   stat = "identity",
                   position = "identity",
                   mapping = aes(y = -pop)) +
          coord_flip() +
          scale_y_continuous(labels= abs, limits = (45)*c(-1,1)) +
          geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
          scale_fill_economist() +
          labs(title = NULL, x = "Věk", y = "Může                                   Podíl obyvatel (v ‰)                                   Ženy",face="bold")+ 
          theme_bw()+  
          guides(fill=guide_legend(title=NULL))+
         scale_fill_manual(values=c(t.col,if ("gender" == "M") {"blue"} else {"pink"}))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Kirill. First. As you are mapping gender on color you probably want to use scale_color_manual. Second. The condition "gender" == "M" is always FALSE and will therefore return "pink". If you want to set the color you can try `scale_color_manual(values = c(M = "blue", F = "pink"))`. Third. To help us to help you have a look at [how to make a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you, to be honest i am new in programming R and I do not know about this. The main problem is to create deferent solution for each year. I am satisfied with how 2001 looks, but I can't make it blue on the left in 1991 and pink on the right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whether I got everything right.

As you want the fill color to both reflect the year and the gender you could map the interaction of `year` and `gender` on `fill` and set the fill color for each combination via `scale_fill_manual`.

Additionally I simplified your code a little.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df4 <- df3 %>%
  filter(year != 2011) %>% 
  mutate(gender_year = interaction(gender, year)) %>% 
  # Sort data
  arrange(year)

ggplot(data = df4, aes(x = age, y = ifelse(gender == "F", pop, -pop), fill = gender_year), width = 1) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels= abs, limits = (45)*c(-1,1)) +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  labs(title = NULL, x = "Vek", y = "Muze Podil obyvatel (v %) Zeny", fill = NULL) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(F.1991 = "pink", M.1991 = "blue", F.2001 = "red", M.2001 = "red")) +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_text(color = "black", size = 14, face = "bold"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(color = "black", size = 14, face = "bold")
```

[image]